# How can I root Remix OS running in Virtual Box?

Tags: rooting, android-x86, virtualization, virtualbox

I have Remix OS beta running in Virtual Box. I've made a virtual drive which I've formatted as ext4 and installed Remix OS on.

How can I get root access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remis Os comes pre-rooted from the the box. If you feel thats not the case please specify the type of (version) of remix Os you have been using.

Comment: Half a year ago, when this question was posted, it didn't come rooted. I don't remember exactly which build I was using.